# deb package script for --purge

Tags: deb, debian

Is there any script that get triggered when user execute `apt purge`? i.e. it does NOT trigger if user runs `apt remove ...`.

Comment: There is exactly one difference between `apt remove` and `apt purge`. `purge` removes files in /etc. `remove` does not. That difference is not in a script. It's in the source code.

Comment: So, if my config file is NOT under `/etc`, there is no difference at all? If so, can I somehow notify `prerm` or `postrm` that it is triggered via `remove` or `purge`?

Comment: Maintainer scripts are executed with arguments that specify what stage of the process is currently going on, so you should be able to use those to do something on purge and something else on normal removal.